# How to automatically detect a Unicode Bidi "attack" within C# source code?

Tags: c#, security, unicode

[‘Trojan Source’ Bug Threatens the Security of All Code](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2021/11/trojan-source-bug-threatens-the-security-of-all-code/) describes a security vulnerability potential affecting programs written in many languages including C#, described further below. This question pertains to C# specifically. I would like to know how to automatically detect and avoid this vulnerability in projects I work on.

I happen to use Visual Studio for Windows development, but it there are answers/approaches for other environments I think that could be valuable also.

My projects include externally-provided ("third party") code in several ways:

1. Externally compiled assemblies
2. Externally provided code compiled to assemblies as part of my solution
3. Externally provided code directly incorporated into my own code

Any of these seem potentially prone to this vulnerability. But 2 & 3 seem to be where I can exert the most control over this issue. But accessing the source of libraries in case #1 to check for this problem would not be possible in all cases.

An ideal solution would be a way to detect and warn/error out automatically if a potential problem was detected, e.g., during the build or even with something like a VS Analyzer rule. IMO a manual procedure would not be sufficient except in very narrow cases where you have code that rarely or never gets modified and external dependencies are never updated.

---

Summary of the problem from the article linked above:

> > By injecting Unicode Bidi override characters into comments and
> > strings, an adversary can produce syntactically-valid source code in
> > most modern languages for which the display order of characters
> > presents logic that diverges from the real logic. In effect, we
> > anagram program A into program B.
>
> ...such an attack could be challenging for a human code reviewer to
> detect, *as the rendered source code looks perfectly acceptable.*

The article cites the [original research paper on this topic](https://www.trojansource.codes/trojan-source.pdf) (only 15 pages total) which details the following:

> B. Commenting-Out
>
> In this exploit technique, text that appears to be
> legitimate code **actually exists within a comment and is thus never
> executed**. This allows an adversary to show a reviewer some code that
> appears to be executed but is not present from the perspective of the
> compiler or interpreter.

From the same paper, their example of a mock C# "attack":

[image]

To the human reader it looks as though the admin checks will be performed but actually the compiler will treat them as being commented-out.

Comment: I guess with widespread usage of IDEs and other ways to highlight the source code - it's not such a big problem. It targets code reviewer, and people rarely review code without syntax highlighting nowadays.

Comment: @Evk the paper actually discusses that in the "Syntax Highlighting" section. Their summary was: *"We might have hoped that a well-implemented syntax highlighting platform would at the very least exhibit unusual
syntax highlighting in the vicinity of Bidi overrides in code,
but our experience was mixed."*  But I do agree or would expect that this will get improved in IDEs over time.

Comment: Even highlighting on this site reveals it. See related question on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412753/should-there-be-a-warning-for-code-containing-bidirectional-unicode-text

Comment: Note: it depends also on the editors (as you may already noticed it, different editors have different bugs). There are also many other possible attacks (compilers and humans see thing differently), so the fix should be done in editors: it is difficult to detect malicious use: we often comments out code. Unpaired BIDI may indicate vulnerability or just a copy/paste. PS: getting display character order from sharper may help (check if compiler see different syntax), but you have 4 or 5 common sharpers (and font rules may mix up things furthers).

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic (and *Anglophone*-centric...) implementation only needs to ensure the `string` value or `Stream` content (after decoding) doesn't contain any Unicode BIDI characters.

[There's only a few Unicode code-points you need to look for](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls), and fortunately they're all [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) characters (i.e. represented in a single .NET `Char` value, as opposed to higher-plane characters that need a surrogate-pair like ol' reliable "" )

```
static Boolean ContainsBidi( String text )
{
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < text.Length; i++ )
    {
        if( IsBidi( text[i] ) ) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

static Boolean IsBidi( Char c )
{
    switch( c )
    {
    case '\u2066': // LEFT-TO-RIGHT ISOLATE
    case '\u2067': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE
    case '\u2068': // FIRST-STRONG ISOLATE
    case '\u202A': // LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
    case '\u202B': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
    case '\u202D': // LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
    case '\u202E': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

A better implementation would check that the content *within* BIDI code-points contains substantial amounts of *atypical text* for a RTL language (e.g. Hebrew and Arabic) - which I suppose could be done quickly-and-dirtily by comparing the amount of Latin-1 characters in that range vs. the amount of Arabic or Hebrew code-points in the same range.

Just spitballing, something like this? (`static Boolean IsRiskyBidi`)

```
static Boolean IsBidi_Rtl( Char c )
{
    switch( c )
    {
    case '\u2067': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE
//  case '\u2068': // FIRST-STRONG ISOLATE // TODO
    case '\u202B': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
    case '\u202E': // RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

static Boolean IsRiskyBidi( String text )
{
    List<Int32> bidiIndexes = text
        .Select( ( c, idx ) => IsBidi( c ) ? idx : -1 )
        .Where( idx => idx >= 0 )
        .ToList();

    var runs = bidiIndexes
        .Lead(1) // TODO:
        .Select( ( Int32 idx, Int32 nextIdx ) => text.AsSpan( start: idx + 1, length: nextIdx - idx ) ) // +1 to skip the BiDi char
        .Select( run => (
            text: run,
            isRtl: IsBidi_Rtl( run[0] ),
            countLatin1: run.Count( c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit( c ) && c <= 0xFF ),
            countNonLatin1: run.Count( c => c > 0xFF ) )
        )
        .Select(  )
        .ToList();

    // If there are any RTL runs of text with, say, more than 50% Latin1 characters then that's pretty sus...
    var dodgyRuns = runs
        .Where( run => run.isRtl && run.countLatin1 >= run.text.Length / 2 )
        .ToList();
    
    return dodgyRuns.Any();
}
```

Comment: You appear to have a predicate in `IsBidi` and a `String` is an `IEnumerable<Char>`. Any reason then to laboriously write out a loop rather than use Linq's `Any`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Using `for(int` with `String[int]` is much faster than using the `String.GetEnumerator()` - if the program is processing large strings it makes sense to do it that way. But it's just to demonstrate the idea...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've expanded my answer with something that I hope should answer the OP's question directly (i,e. how to detect suspicious text), any thoughts?